# MDX OPENQUERY via LinkServer - result me 2.999999999999999E-2

Tags: sql-server, mdx, openquery

I am using Stored Procedure to get result from `OLAP` Cube using LinkServer Object and `OPENQUERY` construct.

Query is working fine . But for the calculated sum of lifetimeCapacity measure,it result as **2.999999999999999E-2** ,When i run same MDX directly in SSMS MDX Query pan this works fine. I do not know how I handle it and why it is behaving like this. Please help me to tackle this case.

Comment: If the number you're _expecting_ is `0.03` (all problem reports should have actual _and_ expected behaviour), it'll just come down to floating point imprecision.

Comment: we have experienced this problem when using openquery against our olap cubes; not sure if it the best solution but casting initially to float and then converting to decimal seems to work. I don't believe a direct convert works.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use float type. Use decimal or double

Comment: Did you mean in the incorporated MDX Query how can I do it. I have applied various format_string but this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Use (the SQL type `DECIMAL(8,2)` in your stored procedure for the variable that holds that value, or cast to it if you're returning directly from a query.

That will round such calculations to the nearest 0.01, giving 0.03 for that alue.

Increase the second parameter of the type to increase the number of decimal places of accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

It's float so initially let sql-server know that it is float via a cast ... then do a further conversion:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(20),"[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Member_Caption]"))  AS [Date]
    , CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2),CAST(ISNULL("[Measures].[SomeNumericMeasure]", 0.0) AS FLOAT))  AS SomeNumericMeasure
FROM 
    OPENQUERY
    ...
    ...
```